# Failed to instantiate module impp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=b...)

Tags: angularjs

I am facing this below error sometimes:- 
Error scenario: - 
when I press ctrl+f5 or sometime login redirect to the dashboard page.

my model code is :-

```
const imppApp = angular.module("impp", [
'tableSort'
,'ngStorage'
,'ngRoute',
'ngFileUpload',
'angular.chosen',
'btford.socket-io']).constant('imppAppConstant', {
   API_URL: "lumen/public",
   SITE_URL: window.location.origin+ "/" +window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] , //'/impp-frontend-v2',
// API_URL: "http://localhost/impp_lumen_app/public",
// SITE_URL:'http://localhost/impp-frontend-v2',
TOKEN: ""});
```

Error is :- 
    Failed to instantiate module impp due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=b...)
    [image]

Comment: Hi! Can you please share your code?

Comment: I have add first jquery then angular but in my localhost no error thowing but when i test it on server there is an error. server is ssl certified

Comment: Maybe because once deployed it can't find your scripts. Please share code where you load scripts

Comment: error throwing only sometime 1 when i press ctrl+f5

Comment: I am not understanding where is the problem so which part of code share with you not understanding

Comment: const imppApp = angular.module("impp", [
    'tableSort'
    ,'ngStorage'
    ,'ngRoute',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'angular.chosen',
    'btford.socket-io'
]).constant('imppAppConstant', {
    API_URL: "lumen/public",
    SITE_URL: window.location.origin+ "/" +window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] , //'/impp-frontend-v2',
    // API_URL: "http://localhost/impp_lumen_app/public",
    // SITE_URL:'http://localhost/impp-frontend-v2',
    TOKEN: ""
});

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in comments

Comment: that above model is responsible after login and all injector is accsiable